# Jsonpath issue using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonpath

Here I have a code that for some reason Does not pop up any errors but it also does not do what I want it to do  which is pull up a list of all the reference Id's from this json file

```js
$(function() {

  {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Account/4611686018429000034/Character/0/Stats/UniqueWeapons/",
      headers: {
        "X-API-Key": apiKey
      },
      success: function(data) {
        let
          NameT = jsonPath("$.Response..referenceId");
        $('#player-NameT').text(NameT);

        console.log(NameT);

      },

    });
  }
});
```

here is the json data

```js
{
    "Response": {
        "weapons": [
            {
                "referenceId": 2208405142,
                "values": {
                    "uniqueWeaponAssists": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssists",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 0.0,
                            "displayValue": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssistDamage",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 0.0,
                            "displayValue": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "uniqueWeaponKills": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponKills",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 1117.0,
                            "displayValue": "1117"
                        }
                    },
                    "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponPrecisionKills",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 1.0,
                            "displayValue": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponKillsPrecisionKills",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 0.00089525514771709937,
                            "displayValue": "0%"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "referenceId": 2232171099,
                "values": {
                    "uniqueWeaponAssists": {
                        "statId": "uniqueWeaponAssists",
                        "basic": {
                            "value": 0.0,
```

I added the json data in here .
It is only a sample of it as the full amount it over 79k characters .

Comment: can you show json code ?

Comment: Yes I added it into the post

Answer (score 1):

you will get `referenceId` from below code, if the ID is more than one you can run the loop and get the other id also

```
$(function() {

  {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Account/4611686018429000034/Character/0/Stats/UniqueWeapons/",
      headers: {
        "X-API-Key": apiKey
      },
      success: function(data) {

    var NameT  =data;
    console.log(NameT.Response.weapons[0].referenceId);
      },

    });
  }
});``
```

Answer (score -1):

I Hope this might will help you. Can you please also share your JSON response in which you are getting an error response.

```
$(function() {

{
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Account/4611686018429000034/Character/0/Stats/UniqueWeapons/",
  headers: {
    "X-API-Key": apiKey
  },
  success: function(data) {
      var weaponCollection = $.parseJSON(data);
      if( weaponCollection.length != 0 ){
          console.log(weaponCollection.Response.weapons);
      }  
  },
  complete: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log("Error:");
  }
});
}
});
```

Comment: How would the OP do with from JavaScript? Can you show some code example?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you improve your answer with some example and more information about your solution.

Comment: @Nicolas sorry for incomplete answer, I was in travel, I updated my answer with some reference code this will help you. if you have any question just let me know